# Why can't the schema owner create a new table?

Tags: schema

I have a DB user called STANMAN which owns the STANMAN schema.  When I try to create a table as STANMAN, it says STANMAN has insufficient privileges.  How could a schema-owner not already have sufficient privileges?  Naturally, when I try to GRANT ALTER or GRANT CREATE, I get "Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but what Database Engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later then to create an table in a schema you need *both* CREATE TABLE at the database level and ALTER at the schema level. Ownership of a schema covers the ALTER permission requirement but not the CREATE TABLE one.

CREATE TABLE is also granted by membership in the `db_ddladmin` fixed database role. This role is for backwards compatibility - do not use it for new security implementations.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't know why I got that error message, but since it's working now, I will live to troubleshoot that another day!